# Is it possible to set the same cookies in Flash as they are used in browser

Tags: php, javascript, flash, cookies, session-cookies

I use js plugins like uploadify, that uses swf (flash) as uploader (to provide ajax upload).
I can perform upload operation only for logged-in people. But as my website authentication happens not via flash, flash doesn't have cookies as browser has after authentication.

So, in browser i am an administrator, in flash i am guest. Is there a way to setup the same cookie for flash as i have in browser to identify myself without additional hashes or other extra functionality?

Will be happy to any help/advices/links to docs/manuals.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript to set and read cookie(s) and then use `ExternalInterface` to pass values to/from Flash.

Or you can use `SharedObject` to set/read your 'cookies' and then pass the values to the website (`ExternalInterface`).

Comment: What do you mean 'the same way'?

Comment: i mean that flash has different user agent/etc (i'm using native).
i will try to implement your advice and then update you :)

Answer (score 1):

As strah stated, through a combination of `ExternalInterface` and `SharedObject`, you can persist data in Flash similar to how you would use cookies to persist data in Javascript. How do you go about doing this, you ask?

First, you will need to write the ActionScript code which utilizes one or more `SharedObjects` to persist data:

```
//Obtain the SharedObject named "cookie", procuring a reference
//to the member Object containing its persisted data
var locusLSO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("cookie");
var lsoData:Object = locusLSO.data;
/////

//Establish a pairing in locusLSO between some key and value
lsoData["key"] = "value";

//Immediately serialize the data contained in locusLSO to its linked file
var statusStr:String = locusLSO.flush();
```

Second, you need to encapsulate your ActionScript code in a method, and then register that method as part of the ExternalInterface of its parent application:

```
function storeData(/*param1, param2, ... */):void {/*code*/}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("storeData");
```

Third, you will need to compile your Actionscript application (your code), and create an element in your HTML that references the resultant .swf file.

Then, assuming the aforementioned HTML element is represented as a DOMElement named `flashDOMElement`, you can call your method with the DOMElement:

```
flashDOMElement.storeData(/*arg1, arg2, ... */);
```

---

Check out [BakedGoods](https://github.com/klawson88/Baked-Goods) if you don't want to go through the trouble of doing all of this;  its a Javascript library that establishes a uniform interface that can be used to conduct common storage operations in all native, and some non-native storage facilities, including Flash Locally Shared Objects.

With it, creating an LSO can be accomplished with code as simple as:

```
bakedGoods.set({
    data: [{key: "key", value: "value"}],
    storageTypes: ["flash"],
    complete: function(byStorageTypeRemovedItemKeysObj, byStorageTypeErrorObj){/*code*/}
});
```

Retrieving and removing data is just as easy. Trust me on all of this, I would know; i'm its maintainer :)